# FLUTTER :MissingPlugins in release installation when image_picker added as dependency

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, imagepicker

I am currently struggling with the following issue in **Android**:
The flutter share plugin as well as the url_launcher plugin do not work in the actual release installation.
Everything works perfectly fine in debug (physical device & emulator).

Also when the release version is run (from vscode) on a physical device, everything is working.

However, **once I install the release version, the plugins are no longer available.**

I have spent about 3 days testing my flutter app and was able to reproduce the error.

I found the following:

- Physical device logcat throws missing plugin exception
- **when image_picker plugin is removed, everything works as expected.**

The internet permission is added in Android.Manifest.
Compile and SDK versions is 29.
Min SDK Version is 21.

I really hope someone could give me a hint on how to overcome the MissingPluginException issue.

Could one force flutter to register the plugins in release?

- I have checked the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java and everything is listed.
- I ran flutter clean and pub cache repair a dozen of times
- I used different gradle versions
- I used different plugin versions

Thank you for your time!

**Error thrown when trying to use url_launcher or share plugin:**

```
E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
11-11 20:36:28.091 23069 23094 E flutter : #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
11-11 20:36:28.091 23069 23094 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-11 20:36:28.091 23069 23094 E flutter :

11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : #1      canLaunch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:124)
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : #2      _MyHomePageState._tryLaunchURL (package:atestapp/main.dart:36)
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : #3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:atestapp/main.dart:65)
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter : <asynchronous suspension>
11-11 20:37:19.084 23069 23094 E flutter :
11-11 20:37:20.273  3896  9400 D ClClient: Not sending keepalive.  Current connection state=STOPPED
```

**Flutter doctor -v output:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.22.3 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 8874f21e79 (13 days ago), 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
    • Engine revision a1440ca392
    • Dart version 2.10.3

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android-SDK
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Android-SDK
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.51.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Pixel 2 XL (mobile) • 801KPTM1379449 • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: atestapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  share: ^0.6.5+4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue!
I tested different gradle plugin versions and had to downgrade from using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` and  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'` **TO** `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` in /android/build.gradle while keeping `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip` the same.